# How to get dependant dynamic dropdown in jsp servlet without using json

Tags: jsp, select

I am trying to display the value to list(select tag(parent)) from database, when I change select list option from 1st (select tag).

I am trying in jsp without using json.

Like the below:

```
<select name="country" id="parent" onchange="">

<select name="city" id="child">
```

Answer (score 0):

First retrive all country and its city and make array of those cities according to country in JavaScript and then based on country you can set city names.